# print preview is not working in godady

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc

I have a web application developed in `ASP.NET`. I am using `rdlc` to do the reporting. Everything seems to work fine on my development machine, but not when I upload the application to the hosting service (GoDaddy.com). The reports show up as preview (ReportViewer Control). But when I click on Print it is not showing the preview.

```
public void print()
{
    try
    {
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("output.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();

        //Open exsisting pdf
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("output.pdf"));

        //Getting a instance of new pdf wrtiter
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Print.pdf"), FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        int i = 0;
        int p = 0;
        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
        Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
        float width = psize.Width;
        float height = psize.Height;

        //Add Page to new document
        while (i < n)
        {
             document.NewPage();
             p++;
             i++;
             PdfImportedPage page1 = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
             cb.AddTemplate(page1, 0, 0);
         }

         //Attach javascript to the document
         PdfAction jAction = PdfAction.JavaScript("this.print(true);\r", writer);
         writer.AddJavaScript(jAction);
         document.Close();

         //Attach pdf to the iframe
         frmPrint.Attributes["src"] = "Print.pdf";
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Response.Write("<script>alert('Error Occured')</script>");
     }

 }
```

I am using the above code for print..

Comment: I would suspect that GoDaddy won't allow you to create PDF files on their server maybe?

Comment: is it allow to change the premission of that pdf file?